# setChoiceMode() in GridView on Froyo

Tags: android, gridview, android-2.2-froyo

I am building an app that runs on Froyo and targets Ice Cream.

The problem is with the `choiceMode` of the `GridView`. It seems that Froyo doesn't implement the `setChoiceMode` (implemented in `AbsListView`) method and I don't know how to fix the problem.
Can you help me?

Thanks
Tobia Loschiavo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using this code and it is working:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < parent.getChildCount(); i++) {
        element = (CheckableFrameLayout) parent.getChildAt(i);
        if (position == i) {
            element.setChecked(true);
        } else {
            element.setChecked(false);
        }
    }
```

where parent is an `AdapterView`

Thanks